# Why are my CloudWatch logs not appearing?

Tags: kubernetes, fluentd, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, kubernetes-dashboard

This is my first time running a large number of pods in Kubernetes. I realized my logs aren't flowing into CloudWatch. Note that it was working well with no delay previously when there were fewer pods to log. The latest log in CloudWatch is 15 minutes ago. I have double the number of pods running now and in the Kubernetes dashboard the pod logs are showing.

Please advice:

- Is this normal?
- Will the logs appear in CloudWatch after awhile?
- How can I check if fluentd logging container in `kube-system` namespace is doing ok?
- Should I bump up the amount of resource limit/requested by fluentd container and are there good guidelines on this, e.g. 20 pods setting, 50 pods setting ?

Comment: Can you run `kubectl logs <fluentd-pod> -n kube-system` . Do you see any errors?  Likely some logs are getting dropped.  Are your fluentd pods crashing by any chance?

Comment: I just saw this comment after i hotfix the issue by deleting and recreating the fluentd stuff (DaemonSet, ConfigMap etc). This does not help prevent or understand what went wrong though. Is fluentd known to bug out after awhile of running?